# Can someone please suggest good books for Rates Structuring?

Tags: fixed-income, exotics, rates, structured-finance

I am interviewing for with a bank for their Rates Structurer. Can someone please suggest literature I can go through.

Comment: There are many books already recommended on this site.

Comment: Take a look at:


[Satyajit Das. 
Structured Products Volume 1: Exotic Options; Interest Rates and Currency](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0470821663) and while at it, [Satyajit Das. 
Structured Products Volume 2: Equity; Commodity; Credit and New Markets](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0470821671)